# Select on multiple ids in a field formatted as json

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json, select

How can I do a select on multiple ID's formatted as JSON?

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM articles as a WHERE "10" IN (a.catids)';

The value of a.catids in the db-field is {"0":"10","1":"12"};
```

Comment: Could you be a little more specific?

Comment: If your JSON is a string in the mysql table, you could use a regex to search for the ID you are looking for

Comment: I have some articles in a table. Each article has one or more category  ids stored in the field catids (in JSON format). Now I want to filter all articles from a particular category.

Comment: @user1291492 that sounds great! Could you give me an example?

Comment: Normalize your table and let your scripts put the data in the database properly, instead of saving it as JSON in a database. It's just wrong.

Comment: @COBIZwebdevelopment It seems all Answers have been given, if one of them solved your problem you should select the 'best' and accept it. (The hook below the votes on the left of each answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no "proper" way of doing this. MySQL has no idea what JSON is and even if you do a text search for the IDs, you'll notice that it's extremely slow.

I recommend normalizing the table. Update your scripts to simply put the `catids` in a separate table.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'll go with that. Was just wondering because storing the ids in a field as JSON was so easy :-)

Comment: @COBIZwebdevelopment you should accept this (the hook under the votes on the left)

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM articles as a WHERE a.catids like '%:"10",%';
```

I included the : and , so you are sure you are selecting the value not the index

Comment: Of course, this query would be extremely slow as it has to go through every single row to do the matching.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for LIKE.

```
SELECT * FROM articles as a WHERE a.catids LIKE '%10%'
```

You also want to look up the syntax of LIKE (because you can search for `%"_":"10"%' and have only the second part searched after and even more complex stuff.

Best you would not store your ids that way, though.